# passing different variables to same page

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, browser-history

I am trying to build a web app mainly using html and javascript. I use a number of different variables in the app that are passed through the url.

here are the problems, I have some links that link to the page the app is currently on, just with changed variables, but while clicking on the links does change the url value, the page does not change/reload for the new values when using  and an href, is there a clean way to force the page to reload if you link to the current page, or change the url?

currently I am using jQuery to set the window.location with the new variables then reloading the page.

also, I have a similar problem for using the back button on the browser.  It will change the url but not refresh the page, so if you have a variable set to 1 you change it to be 2, that works and the page will reload with the variable set o 2, but if you go back using the browser history the url will say that your variable should be 1, but the rest of the page will still act like the variable is 2, until you refresh the page.

is there someway to set a page so that the it will automatically refresh when you go to the page from the same page, either through links or going forward or backward with the browser history?

as per request here is part of the parts of the code I am having problems with:

first is the code for the creating the html elements onload

```
var sel_tags=document.getElementsByName("selected_tags")[0];
var temp="";
if(Tags==null)
{
    temp="\<p>All Notes\<\/p>";
}
else//Tags not empty, and there are tag filters
{
    var click= new Array("",a+ AtTagShow);
    var GoTo="PageViewNotes.html?"
    for (var i=0; i < Tags.length; i++) {
        //if we are showing @tags, or a tag is not an @tag
        if(AtTagShow||Tags[i][0]!="@")
        {
            click[0]=t+Tags[i];
            if (temp.length>0)
        {temp+="\<span class=\"spacer\">\/<\/span>"};
    temp+="\<a class=\"selected_tags_label\""+ 
            "href=\""+GoTo+click.join("&")+"\">\<span>"
    +Tags[i]+"\<\/span>\<\/a>"
    }
    };
};
sel_tags.innerHTML=temp;
```

here is the jquery code for setting the onclick:

`$(".selected_tags_label").live("click",function(){
    window.location=(this.href);
    window.location.reload();
});`

an example url for this issue would be: 
page.html?Tags=#rediculous,#meeting&AtTagShow=true
by clicking on the rediculous element the url would change to:
page.html?Tags=#rediculous&AtTagShow=true

Comment: You'll need to show your code.

Comment: for the variables I am passing, they are all after a '?' symbol but the variables usually have either a '#' symbol or an "@" symbol in them, the app uses user defined #tags and @tags to sort and organize the user's data.  this is for a start up company called fetchnotes, visit fetchnotes.com for more details.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.location.href="page.html?Tags=#rediculous&AtTagShow=true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [jQuery History plug-in](http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/) for setting your site up to have back / forward history. It helps with setting up states on your page, that call data based on what query parameters are in the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

In modern browsers (IE8+, Opera 10.6+, Fx 3.6+, Safari 5+) you have [hashchange](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgggdjt.php) event.

Instead of reloading page, maybe you can achieve desired results with something like this:

```html
<script>
document.onhashchange = function(){
    // do something
}
</script>
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) might be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using query parameters (things after the ? mark in the URL), then changing a query parameter and setting window.location to that new URL should cause a new page load from the server.

If you are using hash values (things after the # mark int he URL), then changing the hash value will not cause a new page load.

So, if you want a fresh page load from server each time you change a value, then you should be using query parameters.  Back and forward should also work fine when using query parameters.

If you're purposely trying to do all of this with hash values to avoid an actual server page reload, then you will have to do more coding to intercept hash changes and process them.  That is easier to do in modern browsers than older browsers using the `window.onhashchange` event.  See [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Browser reloads the page, whenever any of these [parts of the URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) are updated via `window.location`:

1. Domain
2. Port
3. Path
4. Query string

But it won't load the current document, if you change the `fragment_id` part (which is simply a reference to an HTML element inside the current document).

Thus from what you say, I guess you're updating the `fragment id`.

Also this might help to know that `window.location.reload()` method does the work of `F5` key.